# How to repack an epub file from command line

Tags: epub, linux

I unzipped an `epub` file to make some minor modifications. How can I repack it properly to be a valid `epub` file from command line on Linux?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
zip -rX ../my.epub mimetype META-INF/ OEBPS/
```

---

Without `-X` you could get the following when validating it with EpubCheck:

```
ERROR: my.epub: Mimetype entry must not have an extra field in its ZIP header
```

If `mimetype` is not the first in the `epub` file EpubCheck prints the following:

```
ERROR: my.epub: Mimetype entry missing or not the first in archive
```

Answer (score 6):

```
zip -X0 "my.epub" "mimetype"
zip -Xr "my.epub" "META-INF/" "OEBPS/"
```

As palacsint already pointed out, without the -X flag, one would run into the epubcheck error PKG_005

```
"The mimetype file has an extra field of length %1$s. The use of the extra field feature of the ZIP format is not permitted for the mimetype file."
```

because the mimetype file is being used as magical number within the compressed zip file, and the zip extra field feature (where zip programs and operating systems can place non-standardized data) would destroy the magical number mechanism (see https://github.com/IDPF/epubcheck/pull/497). The -0 flag makes sure that the mimetype file doesn't get compressed, which is also necessary for the mimetype file to work as a magical number, otherwise the data at the position where the mimetype file is expected could be compressed, scrambled gibberish.

Answer (score 2):

A one-liner based on the previous answers, which will take the current dirname as the epub name, and the contents of the current dir as the epub: `zip -rX "../$(basename "$(realpath .)").epub" mimetype $(ls|xargs echo|sed 's/mimetype//g')`

Comment: On a Mac, `realpath` is not available by default and you'll want to exclude the invisible `.DS_Store` files… Making the command: `zip -rX "../myprecious.epub" mimetype $(ls|xargs echo|sed 's/mimetype//g') -x *.DS_Store`.

Comment: To exclude any DS_Store in any directory use this pattern with the answer from @FabienSnauwaert `**/.DS_Store`